# Multiply a set of constants (1D array) with a set of matrixes (3D array) in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, matrix-multiplication

My end goal is to train a 4D multivariate gaussian distribution parameterized on the mean and covariance

[image]

where,

[image]

and,

[image]

Currently I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

value = [[1,2.0,3,4,5],[0,2,4,6,8],[80,7,6,5,4]]

value=tf.constant(value)

cov= tf.slice(value,[0,int(value.shape[1])-1],[int(value.shape[0]),1])
mean= tf.slice(value,[0,0],[int(value.shape[0]),int(value.shape[1])-1])

eyes=tf.eye(int(mean.shape[1]),batch_shape=[int(value.shape[0])])


#eyes = tf.multiply(eyes,cov)



normal = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(
                 loc=mean,
                 covariance_matrix=eyes)
```

`value = [[1,2.0,3,4,5],[0,2,4,6,8],[80,7,6,5,4]]`  is an example of what the rest of the code may be receiving.

In the example above

```
cov = <tf.Tensor 'Slice_2:0' shape=(3, 1) dtype=float32>
eyes = <tf.Tensor 'eye_1/MatrixDiag:0' shape=(3, 4, 4) dtype=float32>

                     cov =  [[5.] [8.] [4.]]` 
                     eyes =  [[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
                              [0. 1. 0. 0.]
                              [0. 0. 1. 0.]
                              [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

                             [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
                              [0. 1. 0. 0.]
                              [0. 0. 1. 0.]
                              [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

                             [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
                              [0. 1. 0. 0.]
                              [0. 0. 1. 0.]
                              [0. 0. 0. 1.]]]`
```

My question is, How can I obtain `result` given `cov` and `eyes`? where result is as follows:

```
result = [[[5., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 5., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 5., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 5.]],

          [[8., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 8., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 8., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 8.]],

          [[4., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 4., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 4., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 4.]]]
```

[image]

*Thanks, in advance*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow uses the same type of indexing as numpy, which can be quite powerful.

You can look at details here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html  Note that `np.newaxis` is defined to be the same as `None`.

For your problem, you can add an extra dimension to your data to make sure there's no ambiguity in how arrays get multiplied.

```
import numpy as np
cov = np.array([[5.],[8.],[4.]])
eyes = np.array([[[1.0,0,0,0],[0.0,1.0,0.0,0],[0.0,0.0,1.0,0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]],[[1.0,0,0,0],[0.0,1.0,0.0,0],[0.0,0.0,1.0,0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]],[[1.0,0,0,0],[0.0,1.0,0.0,0],[0.0,0.0,1.0,0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]]])
result = cov[:,:,None]*eyes
```

Using `None` here adds an extra dimension, making `cov` into a 3x1x1 array, which can unambiguously multiply with a 3x4x4 array.  You can use `None` this way in tensorflow as well.

Two arrays can multiply unambiguously if each corresponding dimensions are either the same size, or one of them has size 1.